# how to sum custom data in fabric

Tags: google-fabric

When submit Custom Event in fabric, event data are either show in category attribute (example: itemName) or in metric attributes (example: itemPrice). But the data is not sum like Purchase event which show the total number. Is there any way to set it?

Answer (score 1):

When using custom attributes, there isn't currently a way to show the total number across all of a specific custom attribute.